# Base Characterization of Tychonoff Spaces

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

> $X$ is a Tychonoff space iff it has a base $\mathscr B$ such that -
>
> 1. For every $x\in X$ and every $U\in\mathscr B$ containing $X$, there exists a $V\in\mathscr B$ such that $x\not\in V$ and $U\cup V = X$
> 2. For any $U,V\in\mathscr B$ where $U\cup V = X$, there exist $U',V'\in\mathscr B$ such that $V^c\subseteq U'$, $U^c\subseteq V'$, and $U'\cap V' = \varnothing$
>
> **Hint**: Modify the proof of the Urysohn theorem.

I was able to show that $X$ has to be regular for the reverse implication, but was not able to proceed any further. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So you have to use a dyadic chain of open sets that are nested like in the Urysohn theorem.

Comment: Have you tried reading [Frink's paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373025?origin=crossref&seq=1) e.g.to which Engelking refers?

Comment: Frink's paper uses an entirely different method to prove the converse - it constructs a compactification of $X$. I'm trying to prove it by trying to modify the Urysohn Theorem.

Comment: Also, I had got that I have to construct a dyadic chain of open nested sets, but what's tripping me up is the requirement that, in order to use the properties 1 and 2, we basically have to work only with the basic open sets. That's causing me trouble

Comment: Also, this [classic Dutch paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/complete-regularity-as-a-separation-axiom/8276CD50193881C350DB157B7DAC480D) is relevant.